# IBM Cloud Code Engine: Python app built from source fails to deploy

Tags: flask, ibm-cloud, paketo, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have a Python Flask app in a Git repository. I wanted to deploy it from source in an IBM Cloud Code Engine project. I configured the public Git repo and the API key for the container registry. The build strategy is set to Cloud Native Buildpack (paketo). In the logging, I can see that the image is built. It is also visible in the Container Registry. But the deploy fails / does not complete and there is not anything in the logs.

What might be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging, I found out that for paketo and Python a [Procfile](https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#procfiles) should be used. For my project, it was a simple that made the difference:

```
web: python myapp.py
```